# How can I create multiple screen views in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for windows 7 and I am making an informative application(just text and offline content).
In my app I have about 180 buttons. Each button will lead to another screen. I need to know how to make each button lead to a specific screen? 
And also, is there a way to like duplicate the code and not spend hours copying and pasting the code 180 times?
Check my code below for the first two screens:

That's for the MainActivity.java:

public void addListenerOnButton() {

```
    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
```

I mean that code is only for one single button. Am I supposed to repeat this for every single button?

and also a question, how many classes should I do? 180 main activities, 180 fragment_main.xml and 180 activity_main.xml?

Comment: i suggest you reconsider your design 180 activities??

Comment: @Raghunandan what do you mean by "reconsider 180 activities"? So i should basically change all my app! No I wont!

Comment: Please explain more @Raghunandan

Comment: Why don't you start with 1 and see how that goes

Comment: I believe @Raghunandan is asking you to evaluate whether you really need 180 Activities. Do you really have 180 unique layouts, or do each of the Activities contain the same type of content? If they contain the same type of content, maybe a single activity that can change the displayed content is what you really need.

Comment: @VBCPP I started with one button and I posted my code in my question

Comment: @Tanis.7x No each activity contains a different layout, and it would make my app much much much more attractive and productive

Comment: They need to be different? Or they have something identical? You could fix it by passing different data to activity using intents

Comment: @MarcoAcierno They all have a basic text(they are all identical). Can you explain how can I do it please? I'm a beginner and I need further help and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my idea, since your application is just a "informative application" you can create two activities:

1. Main activity with buttons
2. "Information page"

To do it i need info about how you get this informations:

1. In a SQLite Database.
2. In a string-array

Personally, i prefer a SQLite DB it allows you to improve it without problems in the future.

About the `Information activity`:

Example: in your layout you have a `TextView` where will be added the text which this activity should be passed.

To make it dynamic in your case we pass the string to show using [`Intents`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), in our `onCreate` we add something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntents();
String stringToDisplay = null;

if (intent != null) 
{
   stringToDisplay = intent.getStringExtra (EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT);
}
```

`getIntents` will get the `Intent` object which is created and passed to it by our main activity. `getStringExtra` is a simple method which says to Android: i want to get the string which is saved with the key `EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT` (it's something like a `Map`)

`EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT` is a field which we used to make sure we don't make any error in passing data, since we need to use the same name when we pass it (in MainActivity) and when we read it (InformationActivity)

```
public static final String EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT = "EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT";
```

Ok, we are done.

We now only need to set the string to our TextView:

```
TextView infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infotextview);
infoTextView.setText (stringToDisplay);
```

Stop it.

Now we should go to our MainActivity code and modify our `addListenerOnButton`

```
final Context context = this;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);   

    }

});
```

Well, i will focus on this two lines

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

We need to pass the string to display here, how?

Before we used `getStringExtra` now it's similar (note: it's the same Intent class) but now we need the `putExtra` method, the compiler will select the correct overload for us so we just need to do

```
String stringToDisplay = "Hello world";
intent.putExtra(InformativeActivity.EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT, stringToDisplay);
```

(Note: InformativeActivity.EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT)

With the current code we will always sent `Hello world` to the second activity but we need something of dynamic based on the button... well now this depends on how you get the data.

If it's a string-array, you can save the string-array in an array and then based on the button (if it's the first sent string index 0, etc.).

An example:

```
int buttonId = 1; // it will be a general variable, if it's button 1 it will be 0, if 2-1 etc.
String[] informations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.infos); // in a real code you should move it outside the `onClick` code and put it in a static final field.
intent.putExtra(InformativeActivity.EXTRA_STRING_CONTENT, informations[buttonId]); // it's the same of above
```

If you understand the concept you will know how to adapt the code based on your needs.

There are some cases where you need more info or what you want to sent is something which is better if managed by the second activity (example: in a sqlite database you could sent only the id of the line and read lines in the second activity based on this id)

Some things which you could change:

1. Avoid to call it MainActivity2, it's not so helpful as name
2. You don't need really to save Context, you could just use MainActivity.this
3. Try to make your `addListenerOnButton` more general, example take as argument a Button and set the listener to it.. don't read it from XML you will end up with 180 methods for every button.